# Permanently modify checkbox value dynamically via javascript before php form submission

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

In my web-app, in order to submit a new event along with the user-generated event-date (generated via select/drop-down element), the corresponding checkbox has to be selected after creating/selecting the event-date and converting it to ISO formatted date-string (`dt_iso`).

This is the code I am executing at the end of the onchange event's function call (for the checkbox having id `cbx_e`) in order to dynamically modify the checkbox value after selection. But the code does not execute correctly due to undecipherable mistake.

```
var dt_repl = ";" + dt_iso + ";";
document.getElementById('cbx_e').options[document.getElementById('cbx_e').selectedIndex].value = document.getElementById('cbx_e').options[document.getElementById('cbx_e').selectedIndex].value.replace(";;", dt_repl);
```

I have attempted the following code also, but no improvement as the code executes `erroneously`:

```
var dt_repl = ";" + dt_iso + ";";
document.getElementById('cbx_e').options[document.getElementById('cbx_e').selectedIndex].value.replace(";;", dt_repl);
```

Also I need advice on whether the checkbox value modified via javascript is really possible to be passed via `$_POST` variable during form submission.

Note : As the checkbox value for an non-dated event has absent date-field before its date is selected via drop down, I have set its default field value to `";;"`, and later I want to modify it to something like `";2016-11-26T15:00:00+05:30;"` which is the ISO date string.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect an answer when you've neglected to add the markup to your question? Also, why on earth would you call `getElementById` **4 times**  to find the same element, when you could call it once and stuff the result into a temporary variable, which you then use in place of the repeated calls to find said element?

Comment: I have upvoted your comment ... but I want to point out that I have sampled the only line related to modifying the checkbox value which is breaking the javascript code, as in the code is possibly erroneous, and I am looking for someone to point out the error. I have also tried storing the element in a variable, in order to avoid calling it 4 times or 2 times, but that is not the problem here. Hence I need help.

Comment: Well, without seeing the html code the javascript needs to operate on, I suspect a psychics or mind-readers forum to be a place more likely to help you achieve a working solution than SO is. For instance, a `selectedIndex` property is something a `<select>` element has - this seems not to make any sense at all in a question that talks about check-boxes. Just edit your question to provide the relevant html and I'll have a look at it if no-one else does first. :)

Comment: That being said, I think you have pointed out my mistake .. I was mistakenly using `select` element's `value` property instead of `checkbox` element's `value`. My code was highly dynamic php script working various incoming data, and so I couldn't trim it to post it on JSFiddle. But your comment was very helpful in pointing out the mistake in the only erroneous line I had written. You may seal this question with a proper answer post with regards to the mistake in my code. Thanks @enhzflep